# How can I make my HTTP website become HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https

I have a website called http://jobdirecto.com/ that I want to turn into HTTPS.

The site is hosted in Heroku and the domain I got from Namecheap.

I got the paid version of Heroku since that lets me configure the SSL (and I think that's what I have to configure to make it HTTPS). They ask me for a "public certificate" that I don't have though.

I also bought a SSL from SSLs.com and they gave me a private key but no public certificate.

I am lost in what I have to do now to make my website secure.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to purchase anything. Use Heroku's [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management), which is powered by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/):

1. Run `heroku domains` and make note of the `.herokudns.com` domain it lists
2. Set up a CNAME record for your custom domain pointing to the `.herokudns.com` domain from the previous step
3. Run `heroku certs:auto:enable` to start the certficate provisioning process
4. Run `heroku certs:auto` to see your certificate's status

Please note that

> It usually takes between 45 and 60 minutes to generate a TLS certificate for your app’s custom domains

This will let your site run over HTTPS, but it won't automatically redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS. To do that we'll need to know more about your application.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the answer. I'm just doing this so I can integrate Stripe checkout with my site. For this case, is it ok if "it won't automatically redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS"?

Also, there are 2 domains with .herokudns.com. The one without www is an ALIAS / ANAME and the one with www is a CNAME. Does this mean that I can skip step 2? If not, what exactly do you mean with "Set up a CNAME"?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there should be two `.herokudns.com` entries when you run `heroku domains`. Normally, I'd expect to see just `<your-app>.herokudns.com`. Are you looking at wherever your DNS is set up instead of the output of `heroku domains`?

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm trying to do this or a new app. As for step 2, should I do this in my domain dns in godaddy, and if so, what should I put as the host (I have www for another CNAME pointing to my heroku app)?

Also, when I'm trying to run step 3, I get an error that says ** Apps using ACM are not allowed to have wildcard domains**

Comment: @WilfredoCasasFarach, what do you mean by "what should I put as the host"? Why are you trying to create _another_ record in addition to the `www` CNAME you apparently already have? It's true that ACM can't be used for wildcard domains, but nothing in your question suggests that you need one. What makes you think you need that?

Comment: I was just trying to follow your step 2. The problem that I have is that when I follow step 3 I run into the following error:  Apps using ACM are not allowed to have wildcard domains. Currently I have a CNAME with host www that points to a ...herokuapp.com value.

Comment: That existing CNAME should point to whatever you get in step 1. You don't need two records. And why are you _using_ a wildcard domain (something like `*.example.org`)?